# Remove cloned div except for the last one

Tags: jquery

How do I remove the last cloned div except the first (default) div? http://jsfiddle.net/fj3bpyj2/

```
$('#addContact').click(function() {
        $( "#contactInputs" ).clone().appendTo( "#contactWrapper" );
        return false;
    });

    $('#removeContact').click(function() {
        $("#contactWrapper").find("#contactInputs").last().remove();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose elements but exclude first and last elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439421/how-to-choose-elements-but-exclude-first-and-last-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('#removeContact').click(function () {
    var div = $("#contactWrapper > #contactInputs");
    if (div.length > 1) 
        div.last().remove();
    return false;
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1x8s6wfo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: 
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2qgnrzb/)

```
 <button id="removeContact" class="btn btn-box-tool">-</button>
    <button id="addContact" class="btn btn-box-tool">+</button>
    <div id="contactWrapper">
        <div id="contactInputs" class="contactInputs">
            111
        </div>
    </div>

$('#addContact').click(function() {
            $( ".contactInputs" ).clone().appendTo( "#contactWrapper" );
            return false;
        });

        $('#removeContact').click(function() {
          if($(".contactInputs").length>1){
              $("#contactWrapper").find(".contactInputs").last().remove();
          }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: No. Not removing the divs